# Does Tony Stark come from a dynasty of armorers?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

I thought that the Stark name went back to Middle Ages, but then in [*Agent Carter*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Carter_(TV_series)), Tony's father says that his father was poor and a nobody.

What's the truth?

Comment: Those two statements aren't mutually exclusive; Howard Stark's father could have been a poor nobody, yet the line could trace back to the "dark middle ages". What makes you think that first part is the case, though? Do you have a source?

Comment: I'd say we could trace back Tony's lineage to Lord Eddard Stark of Winterfell, but we can't know for sure.

Comment: Tony's Grandfather, if he was an armorer, would've been forging armor in an era where armor was becoming decreasingly worthwhile to make.  The two things are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are NOT mutually exclusive. However, as of "Age of Ultron" there is zero evidence in the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU) that the Stark name goes back to the Middle Ages. In fact, other than the one line you mention, we have no information whatsoever regarding the Stark lineage.

The [**Marvel Cinematic Universe**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Cinematic_Universe) (Earth-199999) includes both Agent Carter as well as the Iron Man & Avengers movies. So far, Howard Stark's mention that his father was poor & unknown is the only information we have about generations of Starks preceding Howard and Tony.

***Note:*** Please keep in mind that the Stark family from [Game of Thrones](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Stark) is NOT related in any way to Tony Stark or the Marvel Cinematic Universe. Unfortunately.

Comment: Winter's coming,...

 so I built some heating into my armor

Answer (score 3):

Could you be thinking of Marvel 1602? This limited series takes place in Earth-311, making it an alternate continuity, but it contained versions of Marvel characters from the 1600s, including one Lord Iron, who was similar to Tony Stark. This was not intended to imply that he was an ancestor of Tony's, however; it's an alternate timeline altogether.

Comment: Good answer. Can't upvote because I reached voting limitatation for the day.